# Decimal Validation Not working in FireFox?

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I use the following JQuery for decimal validate for the textbox.It was work Fine in Internet Explorer and Chrome.If I use this in FireFox the BackSpace key is not work in FireFox .How to Solve this?

```
  $('.decimalValidate').keypress(function(event) {
                        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to check the keyword for backspace.
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

Hope this will solve your problem in mozilla.But I am not sure how it will work in other browsers.

```
$('.decimalValidate').keypress(function(event) {
    if (e.which===8)
    { 
        return;                                          
    }
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 ||  event.which > 57)) {
                                event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```